# Issue parsing the json response in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have a json response as follows:

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 3310,
        "sku": "BWBCL14KWGF003-BWBCL14KWGF003",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "BWBCL14KWGF003",
        "price": 471,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "4246",
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "custom_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "23243",
                        "option_value": "625080"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "23242",
                        "option_value": "625032"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have the alamofire code to get this response.

```
     AF.request("https://adamas-intl.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

switch response.result {
            case .success(let json):

  if let res = json as? [[String: Any]]{

                    print("res is",res)
    }
   case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
}
```

I need to fetch the item_id and other values from the response.This way of fetching,iam not able to reach inside the values.
How could i parse this json response?

Comment: make a codable struct

Comment: Did you tried with `if let res = json as? [String: Any]` instead of `if let res = json as? [[String: Any]]` but I would recommend you to use `Codable`

Comment: `print(res.first?[“item_id”] as? Int)`

Comment: With the advent of the Codable protucol Alamofire isn't really needed. If you want help with your Alamofire based code, post the code you are struggling with.

Comment: @KevinMachado The root object is doubtless an array.

Comment: Also try `print(type(of:json))`. That's really useful for looking at the type of the object you get back.

Comment: @jawadAli No codable struct is showing error.so wanted to try normal parsing

Comment: @Saranya What error? DecodingErrors are very descriptive

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way here is to use a `Decodable` protocol.

```swift
struct Item: Decodable {
    var itemId: Int
    var sku: String
    // ...
}
```

Then use `responseDecodable(_:)` method

```swift
// create a decoder to handle the `snakeCase` to `camelCase` attributes
// thanks to this `Decoder`, you are able to add a property `var itemId: Int` instead of `var item_id: Int`
let decoder: JSONDecoder = {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    return decoder
}()

AF.request("https://adamas-intl.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items")
  .validate()
  .responseDecodable(of: [Item].self, decoder: decoder) { (response) in
    guard let items = response.value else { return }
    // do what you want
  }
```